# Postgres sql warning problem running post install step in windows 10 home edition?

Tags: postgresql, installation, postgis

When I tried to install Postgres SQL(11/12/13) in my windows 10 home edition  when it almost comes near to complete installation showing this error:

Problem Running Post-Install Step. Installation May Not Complete Correctly failed to start the database server.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjvNB.png)

I googled about this issue but no luck, some of post show the create net postgres user  but in windows 10 home edition local user/group options not available.

please help on this issue?

Comment: Look at the PostgreSQL log.

Comment: I checked log file, it is empty

Comment: Then try to start the server manually using `pg_ctl`. It should show you the errors. I'd also expect that there is a log from the installation itself that shows you the errors.